# Azure Service Bus Trigger Azure Function - Concurrency

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-sdk-python

Quick question for you on concurrency with serviceBusTrigger binding in Azure Function. (serverless).

My overall goal is to use the form recognizer service for pdf documents that are uploaded to a blob (moderate volumetry)

So far i have an azure function that is triggered each time a blob (.pdf) is created in a specific container. The purpose of this function is to add a new msg to my Azure Bus Service Queue.

[Function1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z379K.png)

Now i have a second function that is triggered upon incoming msgs in the bus service queue and whose only purpose is to run the form recognizer analysis and generate a .json with {keys:values} recognized by the service.

[Function2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WrNL.png)

My consumption plan is serverless.

My understanding is that this infrastructure should be able to run concurrent workers. Like having multiple instances of QueueTriggerFormRecognizer functions running at the same time but it's not the case. The files are processed sequentially (cf below every 10s) when i debug locally (IDE : VS Code). Also i though that Azure service bus was supposed to guarantee FIFO. It's neither the case .
Basically i thought the only case i'd have to handle with this infra is the throtthling issue with Form recognizer (15 Transaction per second allowed triggering 429 code)

[VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjwsS.png)
[SequentialOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdaH2.png)

Can you please help on that ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you share your host.json? Are you modifying any trigger settings?

Comment: Hi @SeanFeldman , sure : 
`{
  "version": "2.0",  
  "logging": {  
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Preview",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 2
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Think the issue was coming from the fact that i was debugging locally.
I deployed the functions and can now observe parallelism happening as expected.